# json_decode of associative array

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am saving this array in my database:

```
$voz = array(); $datos = array(); $posicion_movil = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= (int)$total_data["general_total_movil"]-1; $i++) {
   array_push($posicion_movil, $i);
   array_push($voz, "ilimitado");
   array_push($datos, $data["movil_datos_datos-nacional"][$i]);

}

$movil = array(
   "posicion" => $posicion_movil,
   "voz" => $voz,
   "datos" => $datos
);

$mi_resumen =  new MyTariffResume();
$mi_resumen->movil = json_encode($movil, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$mi_resumen->save();
```

Im decoding this json:

```
$mi_tarifa = MyTariffResume::where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)->first();
$movil = json_decode($mi_tarifa["movil"], true);
```

But when I decide to loop through the array in my laravel blade ...

```
@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
{{$movi[$i]}} //Undefined index: posicion
 @endforeach

@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
   {{$movi[0]}} //a full iteration (0, "ilimitado", 20)
@endforeach

@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
   {{$movi[0][$i]}} //Illegal string offset 'voz' 
@endforeach

@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
   {{$movi[$i][0]}} //Undefined index: posicion
@endforeach

@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
    {{$movi[0][0]}} //Undefined index: posicion
@endforeach
```

How can i fix this? I have nothing left to prove and I don't know what else to do.

JSON example that I am saving to my database:

```
{"posicion":{"0":0,"1":1},"voz":{"0":"ilimitado","1":"ilimitado"},"datos":{"0":"ilimitado","1":"60_gb_100_gb"}}
```

Comment: On stackoverflow if something helped you, it would be nice if you accepted the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it much easier than I thought...

```
    $movil = json_decode($mi_tarifa->movil, true);
    $total_moviles = count($movil["voz"]);

@for ($i = 0; $i <= $total_moviles-1; $i++)
     <p><strong>Móvil {{$i+1}}</strong></p>
     <p><strong>Voz</strong>: {{$movil["voz"][$i]}}</p>
     <p><strong>Datos</strong>: {{$movil["datos"][$i]}}</p>
@endfor
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very complex for what you are trying to do. But to make your code work, you are misunderstanding what `foreach` does on objects.

Imagine the following data.

```
{"posicion":{"0":0,"1":1}}
```

The following `foreach` call.

```
@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
```

Will only run 1 time, then `$i` will be 'posicion' and `$movi` be `{"0":0,"1":1}`. You are accessing the key `posicion` on `$movi`. Changing your code to this should make it work. Then do it accordingly across the code.

```
@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
    {{$movil[$i][0]}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop on all items in your array:

```
@foreach($movil as $i=>$movi)
   @foreach($movi as $key => $item)
    {{ $i.' '.$key.' - '.$item }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```